# Destroy a dialog in jQuery UI

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a system using [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) that opens a dialog which basically loads a continually refreshing tail of a log file. It works great, but the problem is that when you close it, it doesn't kill off the dialog, so it still continues to send traffic to you with the tail of the file. Obviously it is not a good practice.

Anyway, the code I have so far to try and tackle the problem is as follows.

```
var $console = $('<div title="&nbsp; Server Console"></div>')
    .dialog({
         height: 720,
         width: 1000,
         resizable: false,
         autoOpen: false
    });

$(".consoleOpen").click(function(){
    $console.dialog('open').load("console.php?console="+this.name);
});

$console.bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
    $console.remove();
});
```

This is the refresh function in `console.php`:

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var $container = $("#responsecontainer");
        $container.load("console_class.php?console=<?php echo $console; ?>");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('console_class.php?console=<?php echo $console; ?>');
        }, <?php echo $consoleRefresh;?>);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) function *[destroy()](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy)*

```
$console.bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
    $console.dialog('destroy').remove();
});
```

You also need to use clearInterval or else it will keep running as long as the page is open.

```
$console.bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
    $console.dialog('destroy').remove();
    clearInterval(refreshID);
});
```

Comment: @Steve can you create a jsfiddle showing it not working - or the problem you are having?  I'm sure it does work.

Comment: I'm trying but I can't get it working, this is a fairly complex site, there's functions being called from all over the place, I can't just link straight to it. Also the fact that it's a development area, I can't release it's location to the world...

Comment: @Steve ok.. so your dialog sends information to your server?  And when you try to destroy it.. it keeps sending the info over?

Comment: You click the link it opens a dialog which is set to load a PHP file. This PHP file has another JQuery command in it which loads another PHP file into a div which refreshes every second. When you close the dialog, using Wireshark I can still see that the page is returning to me every second the updated file, so obviously the dialog isn't closing.

Comment: Are you using a setInterval to auto refresh the content?

Comment: @Steve what you need to do is clearInterval to stop it from running after close.  See my edit

Comment: I think you're onto something there, but the above did nothing :P

Comment: @Steve it might be a scope issue.. Is your refreshId available to other functions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19441/discussion-between-wirey-and-steve)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it already

`$console.dialog("destroy");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$console.bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
    $console.dialog( "destroy" );
});
```

or read this [jQuery Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Dialog)

Comment: maybe $this.dialog( "destroy" );

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem...

See:

- *[jQuery UI dialog close doesn't clear dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3310803/183254)* (Stack Overflow question)
- *[Creating dialogs on demand](http://blog.nemikor.com/category/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-dialog/)* (blog entry)

You need to call `$('#dialog_id').dialog("destroy");`.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is not the issue here - it's the interval that's making the call.

Where you declare `refreshId` do it like this...

```
var window.refreshId = setInterval(function()
```

Then where you remove the dialog, add a clearInterval...

```
$console.bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
    $console.remove();
    clearInterval(window.refreshId);
});
```

That makes the variable `refreshId` global so that it can be accessed elsewhere in your code.  You can then use it to clear the interval that is making the repeated call.

Comment: Yeah been working on this with wirey for a while, however as the setInterval is on a different page it isn't working...